# Why does my navbar display style changes to none?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar, nav

I've been trying to solve this but can't seem to figure it out.
The problem I have is that whenever I try to see the navbar in inspect - the navbar display changes to none automatically when the screen width is lower than 768.
I've also tried to use the toggler for mobile view, but still it doesnt work.

useful screenshots for better understanding:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkCXv.jpg

my navbar is the first navbar from the following link
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: There might be some Javascript running behind. To confirm it just remove all the class names in the nav bar. If still reproducible change the nav element to div to reproduce

Answer (score 0):

To inspect pages without changing the page width, just dock the devtools to bottom.

[image]